# Html report in playwright using Java , auto generated html report same like nodeJS

Tags: playwright-java

Is thr any option to generate default html report using playwright Java same like how html report in Playwright nodeJS.

I could not find html report option using java

I would like to know default html report using playwright java

Answer (score 1):

Typically when talking about reporting it will never only be Playwright in the picture of your test automation code. You will usually be using a testing framework like JUnit / TestNG with your playwright as a test runner in order to execute your tests.

If this is the case for you, have a look into the [Allure Report Framework](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_get_started) which works well in Java.

Example report: [image]